# Are $P(\min(X_iY_i)-\min( X_i) \min (Y_i) \leq x)$ and $P(\min (X_iZ_i)-\min (X_i) \min (Z_i)\leq x)$ equivalent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Imagine I have three independent random variables $X, Y, Z$ and each with positive support;

Now imagine I have an iid sample of each random variable, namely $X_1,...,X_n$, $Y_1,...,Y_n$ and $Z_1,...,Z_n$;

I want to know whether it holds that

$\mathbb P \hspace{-1mm} \left(\min\limits_{i=1,...,n}(X_iY_i)\hspace{-1mm}-\hspace{-1mm}\min\limits_{i=1,...,n}( X_i)\hspace{-1mm} \min\limits_{i=1,...,n} (Y_i) \leq x \right) \hspace{-1mm}= \hspace{-1mm}c \  \mathbb P \hspace{-1mm} \left(\min\limits_{i=1,...,n} (X_iZ_i)\hspace{-1mm}-\hspace{-1mm}\min\limits_{i=1,...,n} (X_i)\hspace{-1mm} \min\limits_{i=1,...,n} (Z_i)\leq x\right)$

So if these probabilities are in some sense equivalent

Comment: First of all $F(x)=cG(x)$ for all $x$ implies $c=1$ (for any two distribution functions $F$ and $G$. Secondly, I see absolutey no reason for the two probabilities to be comparable. Can you expalin why you think the two are connected?

Comment: Ahm that is right - well the idea I had is the following: If we consider the minimum and have postive support the question is how fast the minimum goes to zero in some sense, right? Now considering $Y$ and considering it is independent of $X$ I look for the common minimum of $ X \cdot Y$ but sice I substract the minimum of $Y$ it seems like it is somehow independent on how fast the minimum of $Y$ converges to zero and hence can be replaced by some other random variable $Z$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely not. Consider $Y$ being deterministic, that means $P(Y=d)=1$ for some $d > 0$. Then

$$\min\limits_{i=1,...,n}(X_iY_i)-\min\limits_{i=1,...,n}( X_i) \min\limits_{i=1,...,n} (Y_i) = \min\limits_{i=1,...,n}(X_id)-\min\limits_{i=1,...,n}( X_i) d = 0.$$

OTOH, if $X$ and $Z$ are non-deterministic, then

$$\min\limits_{i=1,...,n} (X_iZ_i)-\min\limits_{i=1,...,n} (X_i) \min\limits_{i=1,...,n} (Z_i)$$

can take values above $0$ with probability > $0$ (if $n > 1$), as there is a greater than $0$ probability that $X_i$ and $Z_i$ attain their minimums on different indices.

I'd say that unless you have very strong similiarity between the distributions of $Y$ and $Z$, it is a hopeless endavour to try to prove anything of that sort.

Comment: Would it help if $Z=Y_1Y_2$ with $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ independent and distributed as $Y$?

Comment: I don't think so. Make a few simulations with easy distributions (uniform on some interval or just a 2-point distribution) and I guess you will see that there is nothing like the conjectured relation. 
Am I right that this is something that you'd like to be true because it would simplify something you do?

Comment: Exactly, it would greatly simplify things if it holds :-)  I only know that supp$(X/Y/Z)=\mathbb R_+$, continuity and $Z=Y_1*Y_2$

Comment: But it is a good idea to rum some simulation - thank you :-)

Comment: I am not sure if you are interested but I realized the following: When considering $\min\limits_{i=1,...,n} (X_iZ_i)-\min\limits_{i=1,...,n} (X_i) \min\limits_{i=1,...,n} (Z_i)$ then the second part becomes asymptotically negligible in terms of the first one; This shows that my statement can't be correct for most cases, even e.g $Z=Y_1*Y_2$ and I assume that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ is regularly varying at zero with exponent $\alpha$, $Z$ is not regularly varying with that same exponent $\alpha$, so it can't hold (I dont know if $Z$ being r.v. at 0 with the same $\alpha$ would be sufficient)